# What's the equivalent of VB ReadOnly property in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

If I have VB declaration like this `Public ReadOnly Property Document() As XmlDocument`, what is its C# equivalent? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public XmlDocument Document
{
    get {return someXmlDoc;}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use automatic properties in C# 3.0+ to achieve the same thing:

```
public XmlDocument Document { get; private set; }
```

Comment: This is slightly different though: this allows Document to be modified through the property, which the VB version doesn't.  (The OP doesn't show the implementation of the VB property, but e.g. this might be a calculated property, or back onto a readonly field.)

Comment: itowlson: Yes, sure. There's no direct simple translation. You have to manually implement the property in that case.

Answer (score 7):

```
public XmlDocument Document { get; private set; }
```

Edit as per comments...  Thanks guys, didn't even try to see if it would compile.

Comment: heh... beat me by one second. :D

Answer (score 6):

Here is a great tool that convert automatically VB.NET code to C# and vise versa http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Rats.  I saw this softball lobbed in too late to post a link to this site. +1

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net requires you to write read-only, but C# you only need to exclude the setter part of the property.

Answer (score 0):

```
public XmlDocument Document { get; private set; }   // For .NET 3.5
```

For Previous Versions

```
private XmlDocument _document;
public readonly XmlDocument Document
{
    get
    {
        return _document;
    }
    // You don't need a setter
}
```

Comment: Won't compile: readonly can be used only on fields, not propeties.

Comment: As in the answer above, `The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item`